# Error handler of Subscribe in Angular 6 is not getting the error message from the ASP.Net Core API

Tags: api, asp.net-core, error-handling, angular6, angular2-observables

My Web application has Angular 6 front end and dot net core API.
The API sends "BadRequest("User Does not Exist")" error if user is already there in the DB.
When I make a API call from Angular service using the below code,

In component,

```
 this.userManagementService.AddStaff(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid, this.user).subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.alertify.success('Registration successfull');
        this.router.navigate(['/users/' + user.id], { queryParams: { tab: 3 } });
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.alertify.error(error);
      });
```

In Angular service,

```
 AddStaff(id: string, user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL + 'addStaff/' + id, user);
  }
```

I am not getting the message "User does not exist" in the error variable of error block of subscribe, instead it is having text as "OK".

FYI,
In the networks tab of Chrome developer tools, I am getting response for the request as "User does not exist" but not getting that error block of subscribe of Angular.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `The API sends "BadRequest("User Does not Exist")" error if user is already there in the DB.`? Debug your server side code to check why the server return this error. Do you have any issue with `subscribe` or server return unexpected result?

Comment: Tao Zhou that's intentional to send error from server and I have issue with subscribe

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I fail to reproduce your issue with web api and angular.

Comment: @TaoZhou unfortunately no, Do we have any other way, so that we can look into it?

Comment: AFAIT, there might be some issue in angular side (some config issue may be) because the message is coming till Browser but getting that message in 
````
error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.alertify.error(error);
      });
````

Comment: Make a test with built-in asp.net core angular template and share us how to reproduce your issue. Without checking your scenario, there is no much thing I can do.